# How to show that : $ \mathrm{Hot} \simeq W_{ \infty }^{-1} \mathcal{T} \mathrm{op} $?

Tags: homotopy-theory, cw-complexes, higher-category-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

How to show that :
$$ \mathrm{Hot} \simeq W_{ \infty }^{-1} \mathcal{T} \mathrm{op} $$

For information :

- $ \mathrm{Hot} $ is the homotopy category defined as being the category where the objects are $ \mathrm{CW} $ - complexes, and the morphismes are homotopy classes of continuous maps between $ \mathrm{CW} $ - complexes.
- $ \mathcal{T} \mathrm{op} $ is the category of topological spaces, and continuous maps between them.
- $ W^{-1} \mathcal{T} \mathrm{op} $ is the category built by inversing formally the morphisms belonging to $ W $.
- $ W_{ \infty } $ is the subset of $ \mathrm{Fl} ( \mathcal{T} \mathrm{op} ) $ formed of weak topological equivalences.
- A week topological equivalence is a continuous map $ f : X \to Y $ where :

--- $ \pi_0 (f) \ : \ \pi_0 ( X ) \to \pi_0 ( Y ) $ is a bijective map.

--- $ \forall n \geq 0 \ \forall x \in X $ : $ \pi_n ( f , x ) \ : \ \pi_n (X,x) \to \pi_n ( Y , f(x)) $ is an isomorphism of groups.

Thanks in advance for your help.